# Why does SO's community feel a lot harsher than any of the other communities?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, stack-exchange, community

For some reason, every time I go to SO after being at one of the other sites and ask a question, I almost always get negative results. I ask just about the same way on every site, and on just about every site I go to, I get at least a little bit of reputation. That isn't the case on SO, though.
Why is this?
Also: please look at my [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9014864/thejavanub?tab=reputation) on SO; is there something going on that I'm unaware of?
My questions didn't get any attention for almost a month, and then they all get downvoted (in waves, each after I asked a question on SO Meta).

Comment: Why? Because of the avalanche of garbage being dumped on it daily. It gets to you.

Comment: well @Won't it does not justify the rude behavior or violating **`BE NICE POLICY`**, although it does frustrate the senior members as they have seen those questions being asked so many times, yes SO is harsh and needs to change the attitude or remove the **`BE NICE POLICY`** altogether.

Comment: [**`HERE`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49315213/looping-gridviewwidget-with-conditional?noredirect=1#comment85678158_49315213) is one user who asked a question which for me wasn't that much clear so I asked her to rephrase the question and see how she replies, but I still didn't reply back it's better not to reply rather than being harsh.

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam that reply was harsh. You did the right thing there.

Comment: yeah i hope so i did the right thing

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Stack Overflow is the oldest and busiest of the different Stack Exchange sites. Being the busiest site, it also gets the biggest amount of poor questions... and in response, the community has become increasingly strict. There are many posts on Meta Stack Overflow complaining about the many poor questions, and how hard it is to keep the signal-to-noise ratio up.

The younger sites are smaller, and have more opportunity to ease new users in. I'm also under the impression that they get less homework dumps, but that is subjective. (Math.SE might be the exception).

Regarding Meta Stack Overflow - if you post there, you bring attention to yourself from the site's veterans. From the users who feel the most concerned about site quality. So there's a chance they'll look at your profile on the main site, look at your posts there, and judge them. This can work to your advantage or your disadvantage, depending on how good they find your posts.

Comment: Site *[Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour)* is the exception. They [happily accept straight homework dumps](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2383557).